# HSQLDB + JUnit + Hibernate: java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I want to run a test with JUnit and Hibernate an in-memory database HSQLDB, but when the method is trying to commit the changes to the DB, this exception appears: (No Spring framework)

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name: SRH in statement [select liquidacio0_.idLiquidacion as idLiquid1_180_0_, liquidacio0_.fkEstado as fkEstado180_0_, liquidacio0_.FECHA_LIQ as FECHA3_180_0_, liquidacio0_.DIAS_LIQUIDAR as DIAS4_180_0_, liquidacio0_.MES_DIAS as MES5_180_0_, liquidacio0_.MES_LIQUIDACION as MES6_180_0_, liquidacio0_.LIQUIDACION_TVAC as LIQUIDAC7_180_0_, liquidacio0_.FECHA_ESTADO as FECHA8_180_0_, liquidacio0_.fkSolicitud as fkSolici9_180_0_, liquidacio0_.idTvac as idTvac180_0_, liquidacio0_.NUMLIQ as NUMLIQ180_0_, liquidacio0_.legajo as legajo180_0_, liquidacio0_.periodo as periodo180_0_ from srh.srh_liquidacion liquidacio0_ where liquidacio0_.idLiquidacion=?]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:505)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:423)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860)
```

The exception occurs here:

```
sesionActiva.getTransaction().commit();
```

My hibernateTest.cfg.xml:

```
  <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.default_schema">srh</property>-->

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping resource="pkgClasesDeNegocio/pkgAdministracionNovedadAsistencia/Liquidacion.hbm.xml"/>
     //And others

    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

My Liquidacion.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class catalog="srh" name="pkgClasesDeNegocio.pkgAdministracionNovedadAsistencia.Liquidacion" table="srh_liquidacion">
    <id name="idLiquidacion" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="idLiquidacion"/>
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one class="pkgClasesDeNegocio.pkgAdministracionNovedadAsistencia.Estado" lazy="false" fetch="select" name="estado">
        <column name="fkEstado" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="fechaLiquidacion" type="date">
        <column length="10" name="FECHA_LIQ"/>
    </property>
    <property name="cantDiasALiquidar">
        <column name="DIAS_LIQUIDAR"/>
    </property>
    <property name="mesDeDias" type="string">
        <column length="50" name="MES_DIAS"/>
    </property>    
    <property name="mesDeLiquidacion" type="string">
        <column length="50" name="MES_LIQUIDACION"/>
    </property>
    <property name="fechaLiquidacionTvac" type="string">
        <column length="50" name="LIQUIDACION_TVAC"/>
    </property>
    <property name="fechaEstado" type="date">
        <column length="10" name="FECHA_ESTADO"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="pkgClasesDeNegocio.pkgAdministracionNovedadAsistencia.SolicitudVacaciones" lazy="false" fetch="select" name="solicitud">
        <column name="fkSolicitud" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="idTvac">
        <column name="idTvac"/>
    </property>
    <property name="nroLiquidacion">
        <column name="NUMLIQ"/>
    </property>
    <property name="legajo">
        <column name="legajo"/>
    </property>
    <property name="periodo">
        <column name="periodo"/>
    </property>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing catalog="srh". This might be the problem: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,137564,137629#msg-137629

Answer (score 0):

changed the schema name to PUBLIC and it worked (PUBLIC should be the name of the schema)  -;) , all other schema names did not work and gave the "Invalid schema ..name " error. Thanks to an old post i found here 
https://sourceforge.net/p/unitils/discussion/570578/thread/a887838e/